# How to handle data in different timezones with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, timezone

I'm storing timestamped data from different timezones in MySQL, and need to satisfy two requirements:

- maintain a natural ordering on timestamps (for index-backed time range fetching);
- display timestamps to the user *in their original timezone*.

Put another way, I'd love to have [org.joda.time.DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) in a MySQL data type.

From thinking about it briefly, I see a few options, each with tradeoffs:

- Use MySQL's built-in `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` data types.  This is simplest, but MySQL's handling here is so broken I'm not even considering this.
- Store timestamps as `utcMillis BIGINT`.  This is simple, but doesn't satisfy the requirement to display in the original timezone.
- Store timestamps as ISO 8601 strings in a `timestamp VARCHAR(255)`.  This is simple, but doesn't satisfy the natural ordering requirement.
- Store timestamps in a pair of columns `utcMillis BIGINT, tzOffset BIGINT`, and index them on `utcMillis`.  This doesn't quite work, since the timezone offset varies in timezones where daylight savings time is in effect.
- Store timestamps in a pair of columns `utcMillis BIGINT, timeZoneId VARCHAR(255)`, and index them on `utcMillis`.  This works, but at the expense of complexity and storage size.

Is there a better way to do this in MySQL?  Alternatively - does any datastore out there get this right?

Comment: Can you store only UTC timestamp as date time and the actual timezone string?

Comment: Well, usually, just setting a timezone on a database connection _just works_. However, as you're dismissing mysql's built in formats, ...  you have 2 options (1) _do_ use mysql's built in format (2) handle the thing on application level.

Comment: It just works...as long as you want all timestamped data returned in the connection timezone.  By returning the data points in their original timezone, I mean that the data points even for a single user may be in multiple timezones, and that I'd like to retrieve them with that original timezone information intact.